# Not able to fetch data using Http API calls in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, ionic-framework

I am trying to fetch details from API with Http Calls in angular/ionic app, the issue is that api is getting called to the page but is not able to fetch the details out of it, i am trying to fetch the details with simple angular expression (binding).

**service.api.ts**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/jason'})
};

const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/con_users";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      console.error('An error occured', error.error.message);
    }
  else{
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code $(error.status), ` +
      'body was: $(error.error)');
    }
    return throwError("Something went wrrong please try again later.");
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || [];

  }

  getDataUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**profile.page.ts**

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

  datauser: any;
  constructor(
    public api: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataUser();
  }

  async getDataUser(){
    await this.api.getDataUser()
    .subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      this.datauser = res.results;
      console.log(this.datauser);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

**profile.page.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let data of datauser">
    {{data.email}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: You're calling `extractData()` without any parameter, but it need the response. Have you tried `map(res => this.extractData(res))` ?

Comment: i tried - map(res => this.extractData(res)), but it gives the following error - 
 * (parameter) res: Object
Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? 
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok, redirected, status, and 12 more. *

Comment: Try this: map((res: any) => this.extractData(res))

Comment: You await an observable. await is for promises

Comment: Tried map((res: any) => this.extractData(res)), but agian no output

Comment: (1) Add the type your http call returns to `http.get`, e.g. `this.http.get<any>(apiUrl, httpOptions)` (2) Specify this type in your `extractData` function, e.g. `private extractData(res: any)` (3) Don't use `async` and `await` with Observables, remove `async` and `await` in your `ProfilePage` (4) Make sure handle the output from `this.api.getDataUser()` correctly, you sometimes return `[]` from your Service and do `res.results` in your Component but `[]` doesn't have the property `results`.